# R reverse the small lines in a ggplot with geom_rug

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: date and var1.
Now I want to plot these 2 variables in a ggplot and add small lines with `geom_rug()`.

```
df<-tibble(date=lubridate::today() -0:14,
           var1= c(1,2.5,NA,3,NA,6.5,1,NA,3,2,NA,7,3,NA,1))

df%>%ggplot(aes(x=date,y=var1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_rug(sides = "tr",outside = T) +
  # Need to turn clipping off if rug is outside plot area
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

And here is my plot:

[image]

But my problem is that the small lines for `var1` are on the left side. I want to have them on the top.

With the argument `sides=` you can change the disposition of the small lines, like here:

```
df%>%ggplot(aes(x=date,y=var1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_rug(sides = "t",outside = T) +
  # Need to turn clipping off if rug is outside plot area
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

But in this example the small lines are representing the `date` and not the `var1`. (`var1` has only 10 values, but there are 15 small lines)
Can someone help me, how can reverse the `geom_rug`-element and avoid this problem?

[image]

Comment: `var1` is being mapped to the y-axis, so unless you want to map it to the x-axis, you will only be able to place rug-ticks on the left or right side of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have 15 rows in `df$var` and in `df$date`. In the former, 5 are `NA`.

One way to approach this, is to define a limited data set with only relevant info for what is plotted (not the `NA`s). This should be given to `geom_rug`. With `complete.cases` we are able to omit the rows with `NA`s in our data set.

You could use the following code to achieve your wanted plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = date, y = var1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_rug(data = df[complete.cases(df), ] ,    ## selected date: not NA
    sides = "lt",
    outside = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already had a own solution.
But your approach is a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you want to drop all cases with NA values while plotting is to use the ggplot2 `remove_missing()` function:

```
df %>% ggplot(data = remove_missing(.), mapping = aes(x=date,y=var1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_rug(sides = "t",outside = T) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you, too.